# Postgres pass tuples like SQLite way

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlite, tuples

I'm trying to pass multiple tuples to postgresql by psycop2 way. Example I got 2 tuple like below:

```
tup_A = (1, 2, 3, 4)
tup_B = (5, 6, 7, 8)
```

The SQL command like:

```
tup_A_placeholder = ",".join("?"*len(tup_A))
tup_B_placeholder = ",".join("?"*len(tup_B))
sql = 'SELECT * FROM abc WHERE colA IN (%s) AND colA NOT IN (%s) ORDER BY group_id;' % (tup_A_placeholder, tup_B_placeholder)
groups = executor(sql, tup_A+tup_B)
```

This work on SQLite, but it does not in Postgres. I know that in Postgres we can pass tuple to one %s well, but I would like to modify the command so it can work on both SQLite and Postgres

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According [Psycopg 2.8.5 documentation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) you must use `%s` instead `?` as template placeholder:

So you code sholud be something like next:

```
tup_A = (1, 2, 3, 4)
tup_B = (5, 6, 7, 8)

tup_A_placeholder = ','.join(['%s' for i in tup_A])
tup_B_placeholder = ','.join(['%s' for i in tup_B])

sql = 'SELECT * FROM abc WHERE colA IN (%s) AND colA NOT IN (%s) ORDER BY group_id;' % (tup_A_placeholder, tup_B_placeholder)
groups = executor(sql, tup_A+tup_B)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I realize that ",".join("%s"*len(tup_A)) does not output the string I want.